# How to add http server to eclipse server runtime environments?

Tags: eclipse, macos, apache, eclipse-luna, httpserver

I am trying to deploy my code to the apache http server. when I try to add a new http server in Eclipse(Luna) from Eclipse->Preference->Server->Runtime Environment->Add->Under folder “Basic” I don't see “HTTP Server” listed.

I am using OS X and I have apache installed on my machine.

How can I add the Http Server option to the list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I didn't have WTP installed on my Eclipse.
[this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F) helped me.
after I installed WTP I can see http server listed in the runtime server list.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse luna supprts the version 7.0.47 or 7.0.43 
So try this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. do you mean the eclipse version?